# prevent vertical jumps when scrolling and divs disappearing

Tags: css, scroll, prestashop

In my prestashop site I have the following problem:
using my mobile phone, if I scroll the page http://www.forwardmilano.it/presta/index.php?id_category=3&controller=category
slowly, when f.e. the div with class="breadcrumbs" disappears, the page has a vertical jump that my customer doesn't want to see.
How can I do editing only my customcss.css?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you present some code where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens is when the `.navbar` gets the position fixed, the height of the `header.variant4` changes, which causes the jump. Thus, the breadcrumbs goes under the navbar.

To solve the issue, you may want to set the height to the `header.variant4`.

You may want to apply the following CSS and it will solve it for you:

```
header.variant4 {
    height: 129px;
}
```

Comment: this seems working but now I have a big white line between the menu and the beginning of the content...

Comment: added negative margin-top to the first sibling div.